# How do I add private data to redisAsyncContext in order to use my data in connection callback?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, redis, hiredis

Now I am trying to use `redisAsyncConnect()` set up with a callback and I want to send my own data to that callback. However, the callback function is regulated in a signature as `void(const redisAsyncContext *c, int status)` and there's no parameter to which I can send my personal data. So the only way that I could do this seems to be using the `data` field in `redisAsyncConnext`. The official page of hiredis fails to show the details of an acync connect with callback revoking personal data and this is part of what I coded:

```
...
redisAsyncContext *ac;
ac->data = (void*)mydata; //mydata has been defined
redisAsyncSetConnectCallback(ac,callback); //callback has been defined
ac = redisAsyncConnect("127.0.0.1",6379)
...
```

Well I know the code above reveals a bug that I assigned value to `ac` without allocating space to it. But if I allocate new space for `ac` before calling `redisAsyncConnect`, will the new space get out of control since `ac` points to a new context? I got quiet confused about it.

**Can anyone show me the correct way to add my data in `redisAsyncSetConnectCallback` ?**

Comment: redisAsyncConnect will not actually connect, you need to attach the context to your IO loop. So you can set the private data after calling asyncConnect.

Comment: Thank you so much. Furthermore I want to ask if it also applies to other redisAsync API like `redisAsyncCommand` & `redisAsyncDisconnect` ?

Comment: no, once you've attached the context the callbacks will be called when they'll be called.